# What does QGIS arrow direction mean?

Tags: qgis, symbology, direction

[image: Sample]

Is the base from the first point of the vertex to the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be in any direction you want.

By default, it is from the 1st to the last point, but this can be easily reversed in the style options

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is the order the geometry was created. From first to last.